# Exclude rows with certain time of day

Tags: r, datetime, time, posixct

I have a time series of continuous data measured at 10 minute intervals for a period of five months. For simplicity's sake, the data is available in two columns as follows:

```
Timestamp   Temp.Diff
2/14/2011 19:00 -0.385
2/14/2011 19:10 -0.535
2/14/2011 19:20 -0.484
2/14/2011 19:30 -0.409
2/14/2011 19:40 -0.385
2/14/2011 19:50 -0.215
```

... And it goes on for the next five months. I have parsed the Timestamp column using `as.POSIXct`.

I want to select rows with certain times of the day, (e.g. from 12 noon to 3 PM), I would like either like to exclude the other hours of the day, OR just extract those 3 hours but still have the data flow sequentially (i.e. in a time series).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to know the basic idea, but are just missing the details. As you mentioned, we just transform the Timestamps into POSIX objects then subset.

**lubridate Solution**

The easiest way is probably with lubridate. First load the package:

```
library(lubridate)
```

Next convert the timestamp:

```
##*m*onth *d*ay *y*ear _ *h*our *m*inute
d = mdy_hm(dd$Timestamp)
```

Then we select what we want. In this case, I want any dates after 7:30pm (regardless of day):

```
dd[hour(d) == 19 & minute(d) > 30 | hour(d) >= 20,]
```

---

**Base R solution**

First create an upper limit:

```
lower = strptime("2/14/2011 19:30","%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

Next transform the Timestamps in POSIX objects:

```
d = strptime(dd$Timestamp, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

Finally, a bit of dataframe subsetting:

```
dd[format(d,"%H:%M") > format(lower,"%H:%M"),]
```

*Thanks to plannapus for this last part*

---

Data for the above example:

```
dd = read.table(textConnection('Timestamp Temp.Diff
"2/14/2011 19:00" -0.385
"2/14/2011 19:10" -0.535
"2/14/2011 19:20" -0.484
"2/14/2011 19:30" -0.409
"2/14/2011 19:40" -0.385
"2/14/2011 19:50" -0.215'), header=TRUE)
```

Comment: This is great - Thank you so much! If I wish to look at periods crossing the boundary between two separate days, say for instance nightly data from 23:00 hrs to 05:00 hrs, I suppose I can apply the same type of formatting but with two sets of upper and lower limits instead?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with easily with the time-based subsetting in the xts package.  Assuming your data.frame is named `Data`:

```
library(xts)
x <- xts(Data$Temp.Diff, Data$Timestamp)
y <- x["T12:00/T15:00"]
# you need the leading zero if the hour is a single digit
z <- x["T09:00/T12:00"]
```